# Error assigning null to a nullable int - "The value 'null' is not valid for property"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this property in my view model:

```
[DisplayName("Region")]
public int? RegionId { get; set; }
```

I pass my view model to my controller, and it fails at `ModelState.IsValid` if RegionId is null. If I pass an integer to it, it works fine.

The error message is:

> The value 'null' is not valid for Region

I've also tried calling this before I check `ModelState.IsValid`, but I get the same error:

```
if (viewModel.RegionId == null)
    viewModel.RegionId = (int?)null;
```

What's the problem here? Why can't I assign null to something that is nullable?

Comment: `if (viewModel.RegionId == null) viewModel.RegionId = (int?)null;` Why are you assigning null when it's already null ?

Comment: @Bala - I looked at other posts on the same problem, and they said to assign `(int?)null` instead of `null`.

Comment: @Steven Bala makes a good point. If RegionID is already null then there is no work to do, just leave out the second line since it does nothing even if it worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Global.asax.cs file, in the Application_Start method, add the following line:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

The issue is that, even for a nullable value type, by default, a "Required" attribute is added by the default ValidatorProvider.

Comment: Do you have any other ModelValidatorProviders that you are using?  In Global.asax.cs, try adding the following two lines BEFORE the line shown above: `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();       ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataValidatorProvider());`

Comment: Is this a bug in MVC? From the documentation it says that this "Gets or sets a value that indicates whether non-nullable value types are required" which would seem to mean that it shouldn't be applying this to non-nullable types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidatorprovider.addimplicitrequiredattributeforvaluetypes.aspx

Comment: I think you are misreading the documentation.  This attribute applies to ALL value types, nullable or non-nullable.

Comment: Documentation states clearly `Gets or sets a value that indicates whether non-nullable value types are required.` I looked this up in ASP.NET MVC3 sources and confirmed it. Implicit `RequiredAttribute` is added only when this setting is `true`, metadata says that attribute `IsRequired` and there's no RequiredAttribute yet. `ModelMetadata` by default says that model is not required for reference types and nullable types. I'm experiencing the same problem, and your proposed solution didn't work neither for me. I'll post solution when I find out why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: -1; This does not work. Perhaps it's something else in "my" project (perhaps fluent validation is also messing with it). But "my" project is already doing this, and without a Required attribute, is requiring null-able fields.

Answer (score 16):

Here's another possible explanation.

I am AJAX POSTing to an MVC action method using jQuery like so:

```
$.post('url/here',dataObject);
```

jQuery will turn the data object into a query string. I use the default model binder to push the values into my ViewModel. Model validation fails with "The value 'null' is not valid for *field name*". But the property is a nullable int. After inspecting the raw POST I find that the data object I am POSTing is serialized into a query string that looks like this:

```
Field1=null&Field2=value&Field3=value
```

and not this:

```
Field1=&Field2=value&Field3=value
```

So model validation is understandably complaining about assigning the string literal 'null' to my nullable int. One solution is to check for NULLs before POSTing. I wish I had time to dig in more but I just switched to sending a JSON representation of the data object which correctly handles the null values.

Comment: It was the same reason in my case. And it was caused by html <select> element having no <option> elements! I added single <option></option> and problem solved. In fact, Html spec says that <select> element must have at least one <option>: [w3.org - Forms in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6).

Comment: Well done sir! That was precisely my problem. I was initializing some properties on my JSON object to form.Prop = null. Changed that to form.Prop = '' and all is happy again.

Answer (score 9):

See here: [ModelState validation fails for nullable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922632/modelstate-validation-fails-for-nullable-types)

The string "null" may be being passed.  In my scenario I updated to an empty string "" and resolved this error.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is not assigning null, it's that the consuming code does not except a null value. The assignment is perfectly valid (although your null check is inverted, and the cast is redundant).

```
viewModel.RegionId = null;
```

As an aside you can use `HasValue` to check for null on a nullable type. Although in reality this it's no different to a null check, just looks a bit cleaner:

```
if (viewModel.RegionId.HasValue)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Technically the conditional is redundant in both examples.

Comment: No it's setting the value to null if currently not null.

Comment: Right. So why not just set it to null without checking it? The outcome is identical.

Comment: See what you mean, the idea was to show the use of HasValue from the example in the question, there's no real context here.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with this.

My problem with this is that I was setting the offending property to null explicitly in the POST. So, akin to what you have, the request would've looked like:

```
RegionId = null
```

In my case, it was as simple as omitting the explicit declaration (e.g., don't say it's null, just don't send any data)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the problem lies somewhere out of the sample code you have shown. I have created a sample application that just creates a form and has a nullable field, but it works as expected. I would start eliminating other variables in your setup until you can to a working ViewModel with a nullable property, and you should be able to identify what is causing the problem.