# Model State is invalid when the method has parameters in addition to complex type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

Method Signature looks like this

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateAccountAsync(UserModel user,
        string email,
        string password,
        string role = "",
        string phoneNumber = "")
```

When the request comes; ModelState is always invalid and always complaining about email, password, role and phoneNumber

[image: Initial Model State]

[image: All the parameters are Invalid according to Model State]

[image: Email has value]

As you can see in the image above; email has value and it still complains about it..

Comment: Are you sure it is complaining about email etc. In your screenshots, these are the keys inside the ModelState, i.e. what values are contained inside it, not the fields which validation errors. Also you can see in the last screen that `Errors = 0` for email, suggesting it is valid. Do you have an `email` property in your `UserModel`? It may be that the value is being used for the raw parameter rather than the user property value or you just aren't setting it

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It seems it's not liking the phoneNumber = "", as we don't pass any value. Is there a way to pass null or empty and have ModelState not care about it?

Comment: It is just part of the method signature. Is there a way to explicitly state required or not?

Comment: You might need a custom binder then - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861365/modelstate-isvalid-is-false-when-i-have-a-nullable-parameter

Comment: That seems to be the solution. Thank You. Can you please put the link as an answer and I will mark it as an answer to this questions...