# MVC3 marking nullable bool as required when it isn't

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a `Nullable<bool>` property as part of my model for which null is perfectly valid:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    [DisplayName("Archived")]
    public bool? FilterArchived { get; set; }
}
```

However, when this gets to the controller action if it is null it fails validation. I've had to do the following to work around this for now:

```
public ActionResult Index(IndexModel viewModel)
{
    ModelState.Remove("FilterArchived");

    // ......
}
```

Why does the `FilterArchived` property create an error in the `ModelState` when it is null and how can I stop this?

---

The exact validation error is:

> The value 'null' is not valid for Archived.

Comment: Can you add this to application_start

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;

Comment: Do you by any chance have a custom metadata provider in place?

Comment: @TacettinÖzbölük, I agree but nullable types should not be as default marked as required. Wouldn't that remove *all* required flags? Even for `int` properties?

Comment: What errors do you get? var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

Comment: @AndreiV: I'm inheriting from `NinjectHttpApplication`, but not using any custom metadata providers myself.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett, I was only asking because I had the same problem recently. A nullable `Boolean` (or datetime...) was "magically" marked as required. I didn't want to turn off all default required properties so I just hard coded a custom required attribute and used it in my `Boolean` template to decide whether or not to render the property. I still don't know why it acted this way...

Comment: @TacettinÖzbölük: Just tried that; no luck.

Comment: @bruce14: Edited in the exact error message.

Comment: Why your model property named `FilterArchived` but error message contains name `Archived`?

Comment: @STO: Good point, I'd assume because of the `DisplayName`. To be clear, there is no property named `Archived` in the model.

Comment: Seems this is GET action. What is query string for it?

Comment: @STO: It's a POST. The value posted for `FilterArchived` is "null".

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett then that would be the problem i think. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7408926/2675268

Comment: "null" is not valid value for null reference. Value should be empty or missing in order to bind as `null`

Comment: STO: That looks like the issue. I'll try it when I get back in the office, thanks.

Comment: @Sto: That was the issue, make it an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Null"  is not valid value for `bool?`

To successfuly bind `null` to model value must be missing or empty string.