# ModelState error: The value 'null' is not valid for nullable field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

ModelState throws an error because nullable field is null.

I have a model :

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int? OrganizationID { get; set; }

    public string Organization { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
var errors = ModelState.Where (c => c.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Select (c => c.Value).ToList ();

if (!errors.Any ()) {
    Person entity;

    if (model.ID.HasValue && model.ID > 0) {
        if (!Session.HasClaim (DataCache.Claims.EditPerson))
            return BadRequest ();

        entity = Repository.GetPerson (model.ID.Value);
    } else {
        if (!Session.HasClaim (DataCache.Claims.AddPerson))
            return BadRequest ();

        entity = new Person ();
        Repository.AddPerson (entity);
        if (!model.OrganizationID.HasValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty (model.Organization)) {
            var organization = new Organization () {
                Title = model.Organization
            };
            Repository.AddOrganization (organization);
            entity.Organization = organization;
        }
    }

    TypeMapper.MapPersonModelToEntity (model, entity);
    Repository.Save ();
}
```

The `'errors'` variable equals to 1. When I started debugging, I saw [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C54FR.png)

Why did `ModelState` catch an error? `OrganizationId` is clearly a `nullable` field. 
I saw [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249665/error-assigning-null-to-a-nullable-int-the-value-null-is-not-valid-for-prop) on stackoverflow but couldn't use the solution because here is no `Global.asax` in `.net core`.

Comment: `'null'` and `null` are two different values.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is trying to insert a string data `'null'` in your `nullable int` field `OrganizationID`.As rest of your is not here, figure out by yourself why `OrganizationID` field is getting a string `'null'` value instead of `null`. It may be a reason of `parsing`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed something in View. I had <select> and in that select I had <option value="null">. I changed it to <option value=' '>

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all validation states at the beginning of the controller action by calling `ModelState.Clear();`. Then add any validation you need manually in the code.