# How to send nullable DateTime in form-data / [FromForm]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make an HTTP request to my controller and send back a nullable DateTime. This request succeeds when the field is populated, when the field (CloseDate) is null, I get back an HTTP response saying null is not valid (for Close Date).

In my controller I have a post method that looks likes this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("properties/{propertyId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BasicPropertyUpdate([FromForm] PropertyViewModel request)
    {

    }
```

Since I am getting a HTTP 400 response I don't get to hit any breakpoints.

In my ViewModel I have a contract that looks like this:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ViewModels
    {
        public class PropertyViewModel
        {
            //other stuff
            public DateTime? CloseDate { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The raw HTTP response (as captured by Fiddler) looks like this:

```
    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    Date: Tue, 10 Dec 2019 22:07:01 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Server: Kestrel
    Vary: Origin
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
    Access-Control-Expose-Headers: TotalCount
    Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:712f8d3d-6af6-44c6-a573-2b9adda915c7
    Content-Length: 62

    {"closeDate":["The value 'null' is not valid for CloseDate."]}
```

The form-data in my HTTP Request (as captured by Fiddler) looks like this:

```
    -----------------------------32591187621655
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="closeDate"

    null
```

Is there some kind of inherent limitation to `[FromForm]` that prevents sending of nullable DateTime fields? If so, is there some recommended alternative that gets the job done?

Comment: Could it be the same reaon as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034324/modelstate-error-the-value-null-is-not-valid-for-nullable-field)? That it's sending the string 'null' rather than `null`?

Comment: Just post empty content for that part. "`null`" is a JSON literal but a JSON deserializer isn't used for this. If you were using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you would either exclude the name/value pair, or specify an empty string (i.e. `closeDate=`) and the model binder would interpret that as `null`. Empty content would be the equivalent for this encoding (looks like `mime/multipart`). Is this being posted from an HTML `form`?

Comment: @madreflection, that was in fact the right answer. Using empty strings instead of nulls fixed deserialization. You can put up an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The library should have serialized nulls to empty strings but instead did not.

Comment: @stuartd, reading the HTTP response it would seem that this could be the case, but it apparently wraps any value in single quotes for this kind of response.  Also, you can see the absence of quotes in the value being sent in the request.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett oh you're right, I missed that. Sorry for the distraction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"`null`" is a JSON literal but a JSON deserializer isn't used to read the form data.  It's being posted as a string of 4 characters.

The model binder will bind an empty string as `null` to a nullable value type such as `DateTime?`.  If you were POST-ing the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you could omit the name/value pair or specify an empty string (i.e. `closeDate=`).

This form data appears to be encoded as `mime/multipart` but the same principle holds.  A zero-length mime part is an empty string, which the model binder can then interpret as `null`.