# Request model's nullable field is always null, despite client sending actual values in FormData

Tags: c#, react-native, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data

I have a React Native (Expo running on Expo Go on an Android specifically) client and an ASP.NET Core Web API server.
My client sends requests with content type `multipart/form-data`, and supplies the correct values for each field. But when the request reaches the server, request (with a Model where that field is nullable) seem to lose the field's value and becomes null, despite being sent a real value.

Client (React Native mobile app, using `axios` instead of `fetch`):

```
// NationalId, Address, Phone, BirthDate are all strings. BirthDate is possibly undefined.
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('NationalId', NationalId);
formData.append('Address', Address);
formData.append('Phone', Phone);
if (BirthDate) {
    formData.append('BirthDate', BirthDate);
}
if (Image) {
    formData.append('Image', Image);
}
        
const res = await axios.put(
  `Employees/UpdateSelf/${NationalId}`,
  formData,
  { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
);
```

Server:

```
public class UpdateSelfRequest
{
    public string NationalId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Phone { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public IFormFile? Image { get; set; }
}

[HttpPut("UpdateSelf/{NationalId}")]
[Authorize(Roles = AuthRoles.Employee)]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSelf(
    [FromRoute] string NationalId,
    [FromForm] UpdateSelfRequest req)
{
    // -----> Here, req.BirthDate is null despite the client sending a value
    var result = await _service.UpdateSelf(NationalId, req);
    if (!result.Success)
    {
            return Forbid();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Some logs:

```
      Attempting to bind parameter 'req' of type 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest' ...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexObjectModelBinder[44]
      Attempting to bind parameter 'req' of type 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest' using the name '' in request data ...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[13]
      Attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.NationalId' of type 'System.String' using the name 'NationalId' in request data ...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[14]
      Done attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.NationalId' of type 'System.String'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[13]
      Attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.Phone' of type 'System.String' using the name 'Phone' in request data ...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[14]
      Done attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.Phone' of type 'System.String'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[13]
      Attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.Address' of type 'System.String' using the name 'Address' in request data ...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[14]
      Done attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.Address' of type 'System.String'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[13]
      Attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.BirthDate' of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]' using the name 'BirthDate' in request data ...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[15]
      Could not find a value in the request with name 'BirthDate' for binding property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.BirthDate' of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[14]
      Done attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.BirthDate' of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinder[13]
      Attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.Image' of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile' using the name 'Image' in request data ...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinder[21]
      No files found in the request to bind the model to.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinder[21]
      No files found in the request to bind the model to.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinder[14]
      Done attempting to bind property 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest.Image' of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexObjectModelBinder[45]
      Done attempting to bind parameter 'req' of type 'Capstone.Features.EmployeeModule.Models.UpdateSelfRequest'.
```

Comment: _"...becomes null, despite being sent a real value"_ - how do you know that? Seems your system is of contrary opinion: _"Could not find a value in the request with name 'BirthDate' for binding property ..."_ Maybe monitor traffic to see what _actually_ goes on the line.

Comment: Looks like something similar was already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276281/how-to-send-nullable-datetime-in-form-data-fromform

Comment: @Fildor I've checked the Network inspector on Expo Go, the correct `BirthDate` value is definitely sent (in my case the field is either not there at all, or is an ISO timestamp string with Z offset, I am *not* sending null, undefined or their string variations). But the first line in my server's controller method already failed to get a value for `BirthDate`.

Comment: @Ezra Similar problem, but mine is that *real values (ISO timestamp strings with Z offset) aren't being sent at all*, rather than failing to bind models and then failing to match a route. My route action still works normally, outside of the `req.BirthDate` field being null.

Comment: Could you show the details of BirthDate on the front end ? typeof Date or string?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng `BirthDate` on the client is either: `undefined` (**NOT** `null`, the string `'undefined'`, `'null'` or empty string, or any other falsy value in JavaScript), **OR** a valid ISO timestamp **string** with Z offset (UTC+0 timezone) like `'2023-04-27T02:50:23.636Z'`. These are the only 2 cases, and *precisely* like that.

Comment: Have you checked   IFormCollection  with HttpContext.Request.Form in your controller? dose it contain the kay value pair "BirthData","your timestamp string"?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng It doesn't, in my example it only has `NationalId`, `Address` and `Phone`, plus `Image` if I do send it (which means the field being nullable still works). On my client, the Network inspector *does* have `["BirthDate", "2023-04-27T02:50:23.636Z"]` along with the other fields though.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED (Kind of)**

I was dumb, and maybe the Network inspector lied to me.

What I was trying to `append()` to was actually a `Date` object, *not* an ISO timestamp string. I just used the wrong explicit type in TypeScript (fix `BirthDate?: string` to `BirthDate?: Date`, because a date picker component was changing `BirthDate` into a `Date`), so it was trying to append a `Date` instead, and while the Network inspector still shows an ISO string, my server can't bind the property at all.

Fixing the types on my client worked, even though the Network inspector still shows the same data being sent.